# Vaadin Sample App with Data Model

Tags: model, vaadin, mvp

Is there a sample app that is fully implemented with a data model. I need to see an implementation approach as a reference.

So far I have seen an example that uses the MVP pattern with a data model. Are there any other approaches to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the [Vaadin CRUD archetype](https://vaadin.com/maven) (`vaadin-archetype-application-example`) and implemented a JPA backend for it. It uses Guice for dependency injection and Shiro for authentication. I made some changes to the archetype's structure to make it more scalable. I'm afraid I didn't get too much further than that in my experimentation.

Feel free to take a look at the repository, I hope it helps: https://github.com/chrisparton1991/tracker